# Can my physical location be detected with double VPN?

Tags: network, wifi, vpn

My company's laptop has a VPN installed that connects to the company's network. No other VPN software can be installed. However, I have a VPN router that has ExpressVPN installed so all devices connected to this router has VPN connection.

If I am out of state or in another country and set my location to my home state in the VPN router, then connect to my company's network, can my physical location be detected in anyways?
I have disabled the browser location.

Comment: What exactly is your threat model here?  Do you want to connect your laptop to connect to your company VPN without your company VPN "seeing" your current physical location, i.e. potentially in another country?  Or do you want to make sure that as your browse around the web generally the websites you connect to think you are at your company network?  Also, what does it mean to "Set my physical location to my home state in the VPN router"?, and how exactly does your VPN router factor into this?  Do you connect it to local internet and then connect your work laptop to it?

Answer (score 1):

If you connect to the company VPN through your routers VPN the source IP seen by the companies VPN is the exit of your routers VPN. This way your company will not see the real IP address, assuming no other leaks exists.

But, the company will see the properties of the IP address from the VPN exit. It can find out that it is not an IP address given by your ISP. It might even be able to associate the IP address with a given VPN provider (i.e. ExpressVPN in your case). Thus, it might not know where exactly you are but it can deduce that you attempt to hide your real IP and that you are therefore likely not at home.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do that is to set a vpn server at home (openvpn or wireguard) + dns caching server. Then use your vpn router to connect to your home. In this case your company has no idea if you are at home or not.

The only possible problem is to have a dns leak (Basically using a dns that is not provided by the vpn server), but using a dns caching server installed in the same vm/machine that you deployed the vpn server fix that issue.

Your computer <---> VPN router <---> Your home vpn server + dns server <--> Internet

For instance in openvpn(v2.3.9+) adding this avoids that problem:

```
block-outside-dns
```

After that you can check if you have any leak:

```
https://www.dnsleaktest.com/
```

Full example with wireguard + dns caching server:

> https://gist.github.com/dockerlead/e9f025264b1b2caeba34f5d85fe1e866

Answer (score 0):

A malconfigured VPN can leak your real IP address. If it doesn't, however, it'll probably be fine and they won't know your real location.